# How can I execute a command after screen exits

Tags: rsync, gnu-screen

launching rsync in named screen so I can reattach to check progress, how can I run a command after the rsync, as is it launches the screen then immediately executes the command?

```
screen -dmS  name rsync
ssh   user@hostname 'rm -r ~/path/*'
```

I'm trying to delete the symlinks of file copied by the rsync,, kind of a "copy once"  I don't want to delete source files though.

Comment: Check out manual page for [`screen`](http://ss64.com/bash/screen.html). It might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest running the command inside screen. You could do this by creating a shell script, but in this case the `sh -c` trick should be sufficient.

```
screen -dmS  name sh -c "rsync args_go_here; ssh user@hostname 'rm -r ~/path/*'"
```

Comment: sorry i was late seeing this but its much more elegant than what I eventually did